# Save Microsoft Azure Face API Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on a Face recognition project using Microsoft Azure's Face API and Visual Studio 2015. I'm following the tutorial (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37893.c-face-detection-and-recognition-with-azure-face-api.aspx)

But after closing and restarting the application, I lose all the data.

How does it work in Azure? Can I store the data to load my application and keep my data? What about the faces stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Face API only runs the analysis and sends you the results. If you want to store the analysis data in Azure, you will need to consider something like Azure SQL Database or Azure Blob Storage.